# how use regexp_replace for replace two arguments

Tags: sql, databricks

I have the following table

```
id var1
1  M
2  F
3  F
4  F
5  M
```

And i wish this table with the next code

```
    id var1
    1  0
    2  1
    3  1
    4  1
    5  0

SELECT var1,
       CAST(REGEXP_REPLACE(var1, 'F', '0') as int) as var_new,
       CAST(REGEXP_REPLACE(var1, 'M', '1') as int) as var_new
FROM table;
```

But, the output is

```
    id  var_new var_new
    1   0       null
    2   null    1
    3   null    1
    4   null    1
    5   0       null
```

I am working SQL on Databricks...

Answer (score 0):

Just use a `case` expression:

```
select id, (case when var1 = 'M' then 0 else 1 end) as var1
from t;
```

There is no need to do any "replacement".

Comment: select id or var1?

Comment: @MichaelGonzalezVasquez . . . Your result set has two columns, `id` and `var1`.

Comment: Thank you very much.